# Google Docs - Spreadsheet - Row selection issue

Tags: google-drive

I have an HTC Desire and I'm using the Google Docs app to edit some spreadsheets.

Most of the times, when I click (touch) on a row to begin editing, the application opens the row immediately below (and sometimes the one above).

This is pretty frustrating and it happens even if I zoom in so much that it's obvious I'm not touching the adjacent rows.

Has anyone else had this issue? If so, is there a fix?

Comment: I get this when at default just because they make the default size so small, but zooming way in I was 100% accurate so I think it's just a usability issue, not something there's a work around for.